# How do I import these Java classes I downloaded?

Tags: java, class, import, jlayer

I'm a beginner in programming and I need to know how to import classes I got from the Internet to my text file. I downloaded `JLayer` for use in writing an MP3 player, but typing `import javazoom.jl.player.Player;` won't work, unlike the basic import statements like `import javax.swing.JOptionPane;`.

I read in some forums that I should move the `JLayer` library somewhere so that the import statement will work, but where exactly? My `JLayer` library is currently in my `Downloads` folder. What should I do?

Comment: Import the JAR file in your Project

Comment: BTW - Coding media based apps. using a 3rd party API is an advanced topic.  Setting the class-path is 'Java 101'.  I suggest you pursue easier tasks for the moment.

Answer (score 3):

Put the JAR containing those classes in your CLASSPATH.   You should know how to use the -classpath argument for both javac.exe and java.exe.  Read the tools documentation.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Eclipse or a similar IDE, select your project, then do:

```
File -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries (tab) -> Add External Jars
```

Use the finder to select your `.jar` file, and then Eclipse should do the rest for you.

**Note**: Eclipse will only reference the `.jar` file at its current location, it does not copy the `.jar` to your current project.

---

If you aren't using an IDE, duffymo's answer will work for you.